# Difference between [attributes:protected] and [original:protected]

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

Please could anyone explain to me a difference between [attributes:protected] array and [original:protected] array in laravel when using print_r to an array?

Answer (score 0):

When Model reads data from table, arrays 'original' and 'attribute' contains same data. When you change the attribute value (ex $user->name='John'), the change is reflected only on the 'attributes' array but 'original' remains same. (hence the name).

When update() on a model is called, method checks what has changed comparing two arrays and construct query only for changed fields. Thus, in the case of $users->name change Laravel will not create this code:

```
UPDATE users set name = 'John', password = 'pass', email = 'email' where id = 1
```

but this:

```
UPDATE users set name = 'John' where id = 1
```

This may not be the only way Eloquent uses 'original' array. I found [clockwork](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork) helpful when you need to see what's going on under the hood of Eloquent.